# Water pressure gauge plumbing adapter

Tags: plumbing

I have the following water pressure gauge.

[image]

I need to connect it to the garden valve, but not sure which adapters I would need.

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: If your in the USA, Home Depot and Lowes both have what you need. I won't specify which parts because you may need to modify slightly if somethings out of stock.  Also Home Depot stocks that gauge (probably Lowes as well) with a 3/4 hose fitting for $10.. I bet the combination of fittings needed will add up to almost that.

Comment: I agree with Tyson. Most hardware/home improvement stores will carry a gauge that has a 3/4 GHT fitting already on it. And it's likely cheaper to buy that, than to buy the fittings you need.

Comment: Here's a [3/4 FHT to 1/4 FPT adapter](https://www.plumbingsupply.com/hoseadap.html#femalethread) gor $7.42.

Comment: Here's [one for $5](https://www.freshwatersystems.com/p-5210-34-fght-x-14-fip-brass-hose-adapter-with-washer.aspx). And the [gauge sold at HD](http://www.homedepot.com/p/3-4-in-Plastic-Water-Pressure-Test-Gauge-DP-IWTG/100175467?cm_mmc=Shopping%7cTHD%7cG%7c0%7cG-BASE-PLA-D26P-Plumbing%7c&gclid=CPClr8q9ic0CFQckhgodgmsGdg&gclsrc=aw.ds)